# Snakemake rules file works on my personal PC but doesnt work on a remote linux computer

Tags: python, linux, rules, snakemake

Running this command:

```py
snakemake -s compores_rules.rules --forceall -c 1
```

worked on my personal PC and I got:

> ```
> Job stats:
> job                     count    min threads    max threads
> --------------------  -------  -------------  -------------
> all                         1              1              1
> hierarchical_cluster        2              1              1
> plot_clusters               1              1              1
> prepare_OTU                 2              1              1
> run_compo_res               1              1              1
> run_fastspar                2              1              1
> total                       9              1              1
> ```

But on Linux, only the first rule runs without any error that can lead to a problem, as the image attached shows.

ChatGPT wasn't helpful beside telling me to check that all the input file exist in the same paths as mentioned (and they do).
What can be the problem?

This command :

```
snakemake -s compores_rules.rules --forceall -c 1
```

should have output that 7 rules had been done.
(On my pc only 6 because the 7th used package only for linux)

This is the first rule that doesnt work:

```
rule prepare_OTU:
    input:
        # microbiome_file=pathToMicrobiome+"/{antibiotic}-{treatment}-{location}.tsv"
        microbiome_file = expand([pathToMicrobiome + "/{antibiotic}-{treatment}-{location}.tsv"],antibiotic=antibiotics,treatment=treatments,location=locations)

    output:
        "preprocess/OTU_clustring/{antibiotic}-{treatment}-{location}.tsv"
    run:
        pg.prepare_OTU(input.microbiome_file)
        print("Path to Microbiome:",pathToMicrobiome)
        print("Input Files:",input.microbiome_file)
        isExist = os.path.exists(os.path.join("preprocess","OTU_clustring"))
        if not isExist:
            # Create a new directory because it does not exist
            os.makedirs(os.path.join("preprocess","OTU_clustring"))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

The rule you show only creates a directory, but it doesn't have a way to produce the output file. So that rule will necessarily fail unless its output exists and it is up to date so that that rule will not run at all.

(Unrelated, instead of `if not isExist:` you can use `os.makedirs(..., exist_ok=True)`)